# doxygen enum showing twice in index when in group

Tags: enums, doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

There is a header file that contains a typedef enum. I cannot modify this header. The enum is used within my project and I need to document the enum. I do this by adding a @enum doxygen command to a .dox file thus:

```
/** @addtogroup constants
  @{
  @enum INT_VALS
    Description of INT_VALS enum
  @var FIRST_VAL
    Description of first value
  @var SECOND_VAL
    Description of second value
  @}
*/
```

This creates an entry in the modules section of the documentation for INT_VALS with each enum value listed as a sub-entry. Each enum value is also listed in the module as a separate entry. The enum table is created correctly in the documentation.

I want to have just the INT_VALS entry and its child entries in the modules index, not the extra individual duplicate entries.

Output is html.

[image: Link to image of example output]

Comment: This is for C / C++ code - all in headers (except the .dox described above).

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I'm using doxygen 1.8.9.1.

Comment: Current version is 1.8.11, but with the 1.8.9.1 version I didn't see the problem you mentioned either. Please try to create a small example and post it either here or in the doxygen forum (including used, stripped i.e. doxygen -s generated., Doxyfile).

Comment: I have created a small example. Three files: Doxygen, my.h, sdk.dox. Content of these files is at http://pastebin.com/7jn2papC.

Comment: I now see that you added also added an image regarding the problem you see, i.e. having e.g. FIRST_VAL twice in the index. I don't know whether or not this is by design or not, probably best is to submit a bug report.

Comment: Might it be that you should use `@var INT_VALS::FIRST_VAL` instead of just `@var FIRST_VAL`? It might be since you didn't tell doxygen the enum that it also interprets this as a variable.

Comment: @gmug I tried specifying the full scope previously (and again just now) but it does not help.

Comment: @albert The image shows the undesirable behaviour that you observe. The elements appear as children of MY_TYPE and individual entities in the tree. Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: I saw it in the image as well, I don't know whether or not this is by design or not, probably best is to submit a bug report.